# ajax - Error with execution of php script and data validation - how to solve?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I made a Signup form for my website. Then, I created PHP script which validates and insert user data into the database and it works perfectly. Then, I tried to make AJAX validation which will apply styles on the HTML elements and show error messages if an error occurs. I followed some tutorials, read answers and solutions from Stack Overflow, but for some reason, it doesn't work. When I click Submit button, nothing happens.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="signupForm" action="./includes/signup.script.php" method="POST">
   <div id="emptyFields" class="inputErrorMessage">
      <p>You must fill all fields!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">First name</label>
      <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control formFieldBO">
      <div id="firstNameChar" class="inputErrorMessage">
         <p>First name must contain letters only.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="firstNameLength" class="inputErrorMessage">
         <p>First name must contain at least 2 characters.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Last name</label>
      <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control formFieldBO">
      <div id="lastNameChar" class="inputErrorMessage">
         <p>Last name must contain letters only.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="lastNameLenght" class="inputErrorMessage">
         <p>Last name must contain at least 2 characters.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">E-mail</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control formFieldBO">
      <div id="emailValid" class="inputErrorMessage">
         <p>Please, enter e-mail in valid form.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control formFieldBO">
      <div id="passwordChar" class="inputErrorMessage">
         <p>Password must contain at least 6 characters.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Confirm Password</label>
      <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control formFieldBO">
      <div id="passwordConfirm" class="inputErrorMessage">
         <p>Confirmed password does not match.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Country</label>
      <select id="inputState" name="country" class="form-control formFieldBO">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Select country</option>
         <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
      </select>
      <div id="countryChoose" class="inputErrorMessage">
         <p>Please, choose your country.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="buttonBO">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**JQuery script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signupForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /*
        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#confirmPassword").val();
        var country = $("#inputState").val();
        */
        var url = "includes/signup.script.php";
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: formData
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP & JQuery**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    include_once "dbconn.script.php";

    $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastName']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $confirmPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['confirmPassword']);
    $user_role = 1;
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['country']);
    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorFirstNameChar = false;
    $errorFirstNameNo = false;
    $errorLastNameChar = false;
    $errorLastNameNo = false;
    $errorEmail = false;
    $errorPasswordChar = false;
    $errorPasswordMatch = false;
    $errorCountry = false;
    // Error handlers
    // Check for empty fields
    if (empty($firstName) || empty($lastName) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($confirmPassword))
        {
        header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=empty");
        $errorEmpty = true;
        exit();
        }
      else
        {
        // Check if input FIRST NAME characters are valid
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $firstName))
            {
            header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=firstinvalidchar");
            $errorFirstNameChar = true;
            exit();
            }
          else
            {
            // Check if number of FIRST NAME characters is valid
            if (strlen($firstName) < 2)
                {
                header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=invalid1");
                $errorFirstNameNo = true;
                exit();
                }
              else
                {
                // Check if input LAST NAME characters are valid
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $lastName))
                    {
                    header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=lastinvalidchar");
                    $errorLastNameChar = true;
                    exit();
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    // Check if number of LAST NAME characters is valid
                    if (strlen($lastName) < 2)
                        {
                        header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=invalid2");
                        $errorLastNameNo = true;
                        exit();
                        }
                      else
                        {
                        // Check if EMAIL is valid
                        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                            {
                            header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=invalidemail");
                            $errorEmail = true;
                            exit();
                            }
                          else
                            {
                            // PREPARED STATEMENT
                            // Create template
                            $sql = "SELECT e_mail FROM hieroglyphicus_users WHERE e_mail=?;";
                            // Create prepared statement
                            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                            // Prepare the prepared statement
                            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
                                {
                                echo "SQL statement failed!";
                                }
                              else
                                {
                                // Bind parameters to the placeholder
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
                                // Run parameters inside database
                                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                                if ($resultCheck > 0)
                                    {
                                    header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=userexists");
                                    exit();
                                    }
                                  else
                                    {
                                    // Check if password number of characters is valid
                                    if (strlen($password) < 6)
                                        {
                                        header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=invalidemaicharno");
                                        $errorPasswordChar = true;
                                        exit();
                                        }
                                      else
                                        {
                                        // Check if passwords match
                                        if ($password != $confirmPassword)
                                            {
                                            header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=mismatchedpass");
                                            $errorPasswordMatch = true;
                                            exit();
                                            }
                                          else
                                            {
                                            if ($country == "")
                                                {
                                                header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=nocountry");
                                                $errorCountry = true;
                                                exit();
                                                }
                                              else
                                                {
                                                // Hashing passwords
                                                $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                                                // Insert a user into the database
                                                // PREPARED STATEMENT
                                                // Create template
                                                $sql = "INSERT INTO hieroglyphicus_users (first_name, last_name, e_mail, user_pw, user_role, country) 
                                                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
                                                // Create prepared statement
                                                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                                                // Prepare the prepared statement
                                                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
                                                    {
                                                    echo "SQL statement failed!";
                                                    }
                                                  else
                                                    {
                                                    // Bind parameters to the placeholder
                                                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssis", $firstName, $lastName, $email, $hashedPwd, $user_role, $country);
                                                    // Run parameters inside database
                                                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                                    header("Location: ../registration.php?registration=success");
                                                    exit();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  else
    {
    header("Location: ../registration.php");
    exit();
    }
?>

<script>
        $("#firstName, #lastName, #email, #password, #confirmPassword, #country").removeClass("formFieldBOError").addClass("formFieldBO");
        $(".inputErrorMessage").hide();

        var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";
        var errorFirstNameChar = "<?php echo $errorNameFirstChar; ?>";
        var errorFirstNameNo = "<?php echo $errorFirstNameNo; ?>";
        var errorLastNameChar = "<?php echo $errorNameLastChar; ?>";
        var errorLastNameNo = "<?php echo $errorLastNameNo; ?>";
        var errorEmail = "<?php echo $errorEmail; ?>";
        var errorPasswordChar = "<?php echo $errorPasswordChar; ?>";
        var errorPasswordMatch = "<?php echo $errorPasswordMatch; ?>";
        var errorCountry = "<?php echo $errorCountry; ?>";

        if (errorEmpty == true) {
            $("#emptyFields").show();
            $("#signupForm :input:not(:button):not(:select)").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorFirstNameChar == true) {
            $("#firstNameChar").show();
            $("#firstName").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorFirstNameNo == true) {
            $("#firstNameChar").show();
            $("#firstName").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorLastNameChar == true) {
            $("#lastNameChar").show();
            $("#lastName").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorLastNameNo == true) {
            $("#lastNameChar").show();
            $("#lastName").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorEmail == true) {
            $("#emailValid").show();
            $("#email").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorPasswordChar == true) {
            $("#passwordChar").show();
            $("#password").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorPasswordMatch == true) {
            $("#passwordConfirm").show();
            $("#confirmPassword").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorCountry == true) {
            $("#countryChoose").show();
            $("#inputState").removeClass("formFieldBO").addClass("formFieldBOError");
        }
        if (errorEmpty == false && errorFirstNameChar == false && errorFirstNameNo == false && errorLastNameChar == false && errorLastNameNo == false && errorEmail == false && errorPasswordChar == false && errorPasswordMatch == false && errorCountry == false) {
            $("#firstName, #lastName, #email, #password, #confirmPassword, #country").val("");
        }

</script>
```

I cannot spot the problem or error. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You need to include the `jquery validation plugin` https://jqueryvalidation.org/ ...and also youy need to `validate` your `form` first...take a look at this little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/amwmedia/sw87W/

Comment: What do you expect to have happen when you press submit?  You prevented the default action and you don't perform any actions or provide any callbacks to your ajax function.

Comment: sidenote: when you end up in having 12 nested ifs there could be something wrong in the code design. (one hint: no need for an `else` after an `exit`)

Comment: I guess your missunderstanding is the `header("...")` redirect. They won't redirect the user to the location when you call the php script via ajax.

Comment: (Hackerman) I am trying to make my own validation script. I am trying not to use plugins. (Devon) Those 12 nested "ifs" work like a charm when I use only PHP to validate function so there are no problems with them. I used that approach from one tutorial. Can you explain to me how this Jquery code can be modified to actually do the job? What should I I change? (Jeff) I will try to disable this header function and I will try to run the code without it.

Comment: @Devon I listened to your advice and removed `else`. I didn't think about `exit()` and `else` in that way.

Comment: @BorisJ., that wasn't my suggestion.  The issue with your code is you're using ajax to submit the form.  You can't use a header based redirect in an ajax request.

Comment: @Devon I removed `header()` function, but I still get no results. Probably I have a problem with my Ajax script. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @BorisJ. because you aren't doing anything after you submit the ajax request.  You need to send a JSON or XML response and react to that response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. $("#signupForm").on('submit', function(){
2. Put all the JQuery validation codes under this function .
3. Change button type="submit" to input type="submit" .

Let's see if this can solve your problems .

Comment: I changed it and still does not work. The PHP and JQuery code which I posted up are in the file named `signup.script.php` which I am calling with `$.ajax` function. Should I use `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`?

Comment: Also, I must admit, in the tutorial I watched, the guy used `$(someid).load(some.php, { name: name, ...})`, but he used this do display various error messages in the field bellow form, but I am trying to use another method, to change styles of form fields and show/hide html elements according to the error.

Comment: Your ajax function is not receiving the data back , that code is missing .

Comment: put a success: and the function to receive the data and display it accordingly